# Unable to POST using cURL

Tags: php, post, curl

I'm trying to POST some form data to a site using cURL. It's not a secure site, and doesn't require logging in. It's just a form used to get back some information.

The form is [here](http://objektifsonuc.com/index.php), and the form action is to the same page (it's in Turkish). This is how I have been trying to send the POST request in PHP:

```
$headers = array(
    "content-length: 138",
    "accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8",
    "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate",
    "referer: http://objektifsonuc.com/",
    "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36",
    "origin: http://objektifsonuc.com",
    "accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "cache-control: max-age=0",
    "connection: keep-alive"
    "host: objektifsonuc.com"
);

$query="il=1&ilce=1%3B18&okul=1%3B18%3B743729%3BTEOGS%2CSBS&sinav=100%3BTEOGS&sinif=8&ogrno=1941&ograd=BERKANT+%DDPEK&ogr=%D6%F0renci+Veli+Giri%FE";

$url = "http://objektifsonuc.com/index.php";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
echo curl_exec($ch);
```

**Current result:** The form page renders

**Desired result:** A different page containing some tables renders

Here are valid form inputs:

```
Şehir: ADANA
İlçe: SARIÇAM
Okul: Hacı Özcan Sinağ Ortaokulu
Sınav Türü: TEOGS | ADANA İL MİLLİ EĞİTİM OKDS
Sınıf: 8
Öğrenci No: 1941
Öğrenci Ad: BERKANT İPEK
```

Here is what the form looks like filled out:

[image: Filled-out form page]

Here are the form headers taken from Chrome on a successful POST request:

```
POST /index.php HTTP/1.1
Host: objektifsonuc.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 138
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://objektifsonuc.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
DNT: 1
Referer: http://objektifsonuc.com/index.php
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

And here is the POST body:

```
il=1&ilce=1%3B18&okul=1%3B18%3B743729%3BTEOGS%2CSBS&sinav=100%3BTEOGS&sinif=8&ogrno=1941&ograd=BERKANT+%DDPEK&ogr=%D6%F0renci+Veli+Giri%FE
```

I'm stumped. What is causing the POST to fail? Can anyone make this POST succeed?

Comment: Try adding the useragent parameter to your curl request?

Comment: oops - i see the useragent in the headers array. however, the cookie value you send in your curl request will not be valid for the new request - I think you will have to GET the page first and use the cookie from that in your POST request?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
//open connection

$url = 'http://objektifsonuc.com/index.php';

$string = 'il=1&ilce=1%3B18&okul=1%3B18%3B743729%3BTEOGS%2CSBS&sinav=100%3BTEOGS&sinif=8&ogrno=1941&ograd=BERKANT+%DDPEK&ogr=%D6%F0renci+Veli+Giri%FE';

$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($string));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work. How could _fewer_ headers be a better solution?